# Find Next based on criteria Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to identify the next record for an item based on day, then attribute that record if a criteria is met.  So example from my table, load date, then 3 columns.  I would want to identify when x3 changed for a future load date, with a matching X1.  So the record I would want to find is on 15-sep-16 X2 of A went to 477.89 on 16-sep-16.  The added bonus would be to flag the line if + or - 3% of the starting process.

```
aload_dt    x1      x2   x3
10-Sep-16   1003    A   479.99
11-Sep-16   1003    A   479.99
12-Sep-16   1004    A   479.99
13-Sep-16   1003    A   479.99
14-Sep-16   1003    B   479.99
15-Sep-16   1003    A   479.99
16-Sep-16   1003    A   477.89
17-Sep-16   1003    A   478.99
18-Sep-16   1003    A   478.99
19-Sep-16   1003    A   478.99
20-Sep-16   1003    A   478.99
```

Comment: Do you expect a solution through vba-code or SQL? You should add the VBA and SQL tag so more people can see your question because either way will probably be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!  SQL would be preferred.